# Proof involving Images and Kernels

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map. Prove:
$$\operatorname{Im}A \cap \operatorname{Ker}A=\{0 \} \Rightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{N}:\operatorname{Ker}A^{n}=\operatorname{Ker}A$$

Here's my work:

I tried to prove both inclusions. If $x \in \operatorname{Ker}A$, then obviously $x \in \operatorname{Ker}A^{n}$, because in a vector space $0$ always maps to $0$. I got stuck on the second inclusion.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x \in V$ be in $\mathrm{ker}(A^{n})$ then, by definition, you have : $A^{n}x = 0$. It also writes :

$$A \left( A^{n-1}x \right) = 0 $$

Therefore, $A^{n-1}x$ is in $\mathrm{ker}(A)$ since $A(A^{n-1}x)=0$ and it is also in $\mathrm{Im}(A)$ (for $n \geq 2$). Using that $\mathrm{Im}(A) \cap \mathrm{ker}(A) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, you get $A^{n-1}x=0$.

By induction on $n$, you get $Ax=0$. So, $x \in \mathrm{ker}(A)$.